# expr substitution segmentation fault 'type error'

Tags: c++, z3

I use z3 c++ api. I create a copy from exprs in expr_vector1 and store them in new expr_vector2 and then call

```
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < exprs_vector1.size();++j){
            expr v = exprs_vector1[j];
            uint32_t size; // it is initialized somehow.

            std::stringstream name;
            name << v <<"_"<< i;
            expr var(ctx);
            if(v.is_bool())
                var = sctx->ctx.bool_const(name.str().c_str());
            else if(v.is_bv())
                var = sctx->ctx.bv_const(name.str().c_str(), size);
            exprs_vector2.push_back(var);

            }    
       formula.substitute( expr_vactor1, expr_vector2); // this line causes error
```

but I get z3 exception with message "type error".
Note that these two vector have the same size and their expressions correspondingly have the same sort and exprs are kind of bool or bitvector. I can't guess the reason of this event.
the contents of vector1 :

|popcnt::i!0@1#1_1|

and in vector2 we have :

|\|popcnt::i!0@1#1_1\|_1|

both of above expressions are the sort of bitvector32.

the formula doesn't have any expressions of expr_vector1, can it be the reason of this exception?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] with the exact error text?

Comment: I edited my question and z3 exception error message is simply "type error".

Comment: Which of these lines causes the error?

Comment: Could you simply print all expressions in expr_vector1 and expr_vector2? That would likely show you which of them is a problem.

Comment: I added your answer to my question.

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but is size ever initialized.  In it's current form, it is used but never initialized.  Don't know if it is a bug or if the comment is meant to say you initialize it somehow.

Comment: I meant it is initialized somehow.

Comment: We mean your program has a problem somewhere.

Comment: You could create a log using Z3_open_log("z3.log") before any other operations to create a replayable log file of the calls into Z3 that cause the exception. Then share this log over GitHub.com/Z3prover/z3 issues.

Comment: I run the above instrument : "Z3_open_log("z3.log")" and received a file that contains some number and alphabets. it is not understandable for me. do you mean generating this file?